# CoreData Swift 3 - How to join two Entities?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, nspredicate

I have two entities "CAR" and "COLOUR".

In "COLOUR" i have two attributes.

1. id
2. name

In "CAR" i have three attributes.

1. id
2. colourId
3. carName

id of "COLOUR" related to colourId in "CAR".

Please anyone help me to write a predicate for generating array of cars under one colour ?

Comment: You need to create the `relationship` between `COLOUR` and `CAR`. Don't add only the `colourID`. Otherwise you will need two queries first to get the COLOUR-id from given `COLOUR` and then get the `CAR`'s from the COLOUR-id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not do this. Using foreign keys is something that you do in a database. CoreData is not a database.

In the data model create a relationship in the car called "color" and set its type to `color`.

Then in the colour create a "many" relationship called `cars` and set its type to `car`.

Now you have a property in `Car` called `color` that will contain the colour object.

And a property in `Color` called `cars` that will be a set of all the `Cars` that have that colour.

Comment: Ok Done, How i will write a fetch predicate for getting the relations ?

Comment: @DevidasMDas you don't need to. Just fetch the `car` and then to get the color use... `car.color`. Or if you want to get all the cars for a particular color then get the `color` and use `color.cars`. There is no need to **join** anything. Just use the relationship property.

Comment: @DevidasMDas You could create a fetch predicate for `Car` like this also... `color.id == 1` for instance. This will then fetch all cars where the `color` property has an `id` property of 1. Or `color.name == "blue"` and this will do the same.